# Where is the source code of Android Architecture Components?

Tags: android, android-source, repo, android-architecture-components

Can't find the source code of new Android Architecture Components. Was it published? If it was, where?

If the source is in AOSP, please specify which specific repo project should I use with `repo sync [PROJ_NAME]` in order to get it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is the source for
[Lifecycle](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle), [Room](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/room), [Paging](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/paging) and [ViewModel](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/lifecycle/viewmodel).

Comment: Try [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/room) for the other ones

Comment: Links are dead!

Answer (score 7):

As confirmed by Adam Powell, the source code of Architectural Components can be obtained only with the artifacts themselves:

[image]

Comment: This is misleading. The source is accessible on https://android.googlesource.com, as others pointed out.

Answer (score 4):

**Edit: Android Code Search**

There is a very handy official online code search platform for Android:
https://cs.android.com/
[image]

Try it, you'll love it!

**Original Answer**

As stated in Android team's official blog [AndroidX Development is Now Even Better](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/07/androidx-development-is-now-even-better.html), the source code of AndroidX (previously support) lies in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev. You can see **AOSP AndroidX Contribution Guide** on the page. There are details about:

- How to download the source code using *repo*
- How to build the project
- How to contribute to the project

All you need to do is following the instructions step by step, it won't take long to setup.

The other two useful links are:

- [r.android.com Gerrit review tool](https://android-review.googlesource.com/q/project:platform/frameworks/support+status:open)
- [public AndroidX tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192731&template=842428)

It is also worth to be mentioned that in [Android Fireside Chat (Android Dev Summit '18)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV3iN4PIB5U), the Android team are considering moving the source code of AndroidX to GitHub. We'll see whether it would happen in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the whole androidx libraries collection from [this link](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+archive/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev.tar.gz).

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from AOSP. After [configuring the environment for downloading AOSP](https://source.android.com/source/downloading), you can sync it by:

`repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b ub-supportlib-master
repo sync`

The branch `ub-supportlib-master` contains all sources of the Android Architecture Components.